# WindowsFormsHost ZOrder

Tags: wpf, z-order

It appears WindowsFormsHost control is set to display on top. Is there any way to change its z-order to allow other WPF controls on the same window to be visible on top of the WindowsFormsHost control?

Comment: You may want to try embedding the usercontrols inside a "Popup." This is a little late, but I was having a similar issue. If you want details on how to code it up, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11348291/865883) might be useful. Not sure if you're still working on your project after 2 years though..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately no, because of the way the winformshost is composited into a WPF window it must appear on top.

See the z-order paragraph from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952.aspx).

> In a WPF user interface, you can change the z-order of elements to
>   control overlapping behavior. A hosted Windows Forms control is drawn
>   in a separate HWND, so it is always drawn on top of WPF elements.
>
> A hosted Windows Forms control is also drawn on top of any Adorner
>   elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick. When you declare an `WindowsFormsHost`, it's parent is first HWND component. Usually it's root window. So, clip area for controls is whole window. I'll show an example with WPF `ScrollViewer`.

```xml
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Margin="20,50">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource StringArray}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WindowsFormsHost>
                            <wf:Button />
                        </WindowsFormsHost>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this case `Button`s will be out of `ScrollViewer` bounds. But there's a way to create "intermediate" HWND item to clip `WinForms` area over `ScrollViewer`. Just place another `WindowsFormsHost` with `ElementHost` like below:

```xml
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost Margin="20,50">
        <ElementHost x:Name="This is a clip container">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource StringArray}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WindowsFormsHost>
                                <wf:Button />
                            </WindowsFormsHost>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ElementHost>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Now clip area for `Button`s is `ElementHost` and `WinForms` `Button`s will be clipped by it on scrolling. Also you can create `ControlTemplate` for `ContentContol` and reuse it where you need it.

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ClipContainer" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <ElementHost>
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ElementHost>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</ControlTemplate>
```

```xml
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ClipContainer}" Margin="20,50">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource StringArray}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WindowsFormsHost>
                            <wf:Button />
                        </WindowsFormsHost>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```