# How to draw line on Windowsformhost usercontrol in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to draw something on a windowsformhost usercontrol in wpf.
try OnPaint but it doesn't apear anything
try zindex but unsuccessful
try windowsformhost on a windowsformhost but unsuccessful. because windowsformhost can't be transparent
any other Idea??

Comment: You can't change the Z-Index of a WIndowsFormsHost. Btw a possible hack is to use a PopUp as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248384/toolbar-overlay-over-windowsformshost

Comment: I would consider what's involved in replacing whatever is in your windowsformhost with wpf.